# Android Studio: make application depending on sources of third-party library

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea, android-studio

I got in troubles when trying to put dependncies on my project on third-party library. I tried to depend on the same lib from maven, but version in maven is not up-to-date, however downloaded package has latest changes.

Downloaded folder has only 'src', 'pom' and '.gitignore' in it. When I try to import project into Android Studio and then put dependencies, I can't because Android Studio only wants Gradle or Eclipse project to be imported. I tried to create at least IntelliJ project from existing sources, however after I still cannot set dependencies as Android Studio requires just Gradle or Eclipse project. Can you help me with that dependencies issue? Thanks.

Comment: Which dependency and which version?

Comment: com.github.mhendred.face4j:face4j-core:1.6.2 and on GitHub there is com.github.mhendred.face4j:face4j-core:1.6.3-SNAPSHOT which has couple of updated API endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options here:

1. In general you should depend on a compiled binary. The best would be to find it in one of the repositories (e.g. jcenter or maven central) and then declare it in your gradle build.
2. If this dependency does not exist in any repository, but available to download in another format (maybe a zip file with jar files inside or something), you can put the jar file into the lib folder of your project.
3. As a last resort you can check out the sources, build it with Maven (you have to have Maven installed and included in your path) by running `mvn install`. After you done that (assuming the project is built successfully), you can put the jar from the `build` folder into your `lib` folder, or add `maven` plugin to your `build.gradle` that will find the jar file automatically in your local machine cache.

In any of the later two cases, you're more than welcome to ask the developer to publish its project binaries to Bintray. That will allow the right usage (#1) to all the rest of the users.

Comment: I tried to compile using mvn install on my own and I can't do this error: 

[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.5:sign (sign-artifacts) @ face4j-core ---
gpg: error loading `iconv.dll': The specified module could not be found.


gpg: please see http://www.gnupg.org/download/iconv.html for more information
gpg: NOTE: --use-agent is not available in this version
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available

So only 3 case is applicable, but is it the right way to find out way to send message to a author of the third-party tools?

Comment: Nvm, I made some changes to dependencies and was able to recompile it. Marking your answer as correct. Thanks.